# How to read word file in MVC 3 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, docx

i have a project using asp.net mvc 3 C#. and now i want to have a view that can read word file. i want it looks like SkyDrive, just select the word file (.docx) and then it will show the file in my view. i don't have any idea how to start, can you explain me how to make it happen ?

thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you asking for help reading the files (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215620/how-to-load-ms-word-document-in-c-sharp-net?rq=1) or with design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Open Xml SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124). It's free, you don't need any Office libraries and there are many resources on the web. [This one](http://openxmldeveloper.org/), for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to show an image of the document then you can open the .docx file as a zip and extract the docProps\thumbnail.wmf file.